# A Borel set whose projection onto the first coordinate is not a Borel set

Tags: measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

I am working on measurable sets and I have been coming across this, so called "fact" about unit circle. More precisely, some of proofs I am studying based on the following observation:

> There is a Borel set in the unit square whose projection onto the first coordinate is not a Borel set in the interval $[0,1]$.

I can't give a proof or visual image of this set. I thought two- dimensional Cantor sets i.e., $\mathcal{C}\times \mathcal{C}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The other answers are absolutely correct; let me add to them by giving an *explicit* example of such a set.

There is (think Godel numbering) a way to represent linear orderings with domain $\mathbb{N}$ by real numbers. Similarly, we can represent infinite sequences of natural numbers by real numbers. So we can define the following set:

> $X$ is the set of pairs $(r, s)$ of real numbers such that $r$ codes a linear ordering and $s$ codes an infinite descending sequence through (the linear order coded by) $r$.

Let $Y$ be the projection of $X$ onto the first coordinate; then $Y$ is the set of reals which code non-well-orderings (or which fail to code linear orderings). This set, it turns out, is non-Borel! Meanwhile - as long as the coding scheme we used above is non-silly - $X$ *is* Borel.

Most of this is fairly straightforward; the hard part, of course, is proving that $Y$ is indeed not Borel. This is a bit technical, so I'm not going to get into it here; the citations in the other answers say more.

Comment: Cool.There's some hand waving at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1857699  that I "know" is correct; if you felt like confirming that I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Been thinking about this, I think it's starting to make sense. The set $X$ is defined by finitely man conditions, each of which involves finitely many quantifiers over $\Bbb N$. So $X$ is Borel, in fact it appears at some finite stage of the hierarchy. On the other hand the definition of $Y$ involves quantifying over all _sequences_. Not a proof that $Y$ is not Borel, but it makes it clear that $Y$ is not "obviously" Borel the way $X$ is. Heh.

Comment: Regarding how one proves that $Y$ is not Borel, you could tell me something. A set of relations on $\Bbb N$ is the same as $S\in\mathcal P(K)$, where $K=\mathcal P(\Bbb N\times\Bbb N)$, the Cantor set. "All one has to do" is concoct a property $P$ such that (i) it's straightforward to show that every Borel set $S$ satisfes $P$ and (ii) $P(S)$ implies that $S\ne Y$. No hints regarding what such a $P$ might be please, but **Q**: _Is_ there a $P$ such that once I figure out what $P$ is the rest should work?

Answer (score 8):

You are not alone in finding this tough, as Lebesgue himself believed (in 1905) he had proved that the projection of a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ onto one of the axes was a Borel set. His error was discovered by [Souslin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Souslin) which lead (I believe) to the process of Souslin schemes/hierarchy that he developed to investigate this problem.

R. M. Dudley "[Real Analysis and Probability](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Analysis-Probability-Cambridge-Advanced-Mathematics/dp/0521007542)"

In my oldish edition it is covered in chapter 13, although my edition is by Chapman and Hall, whereas the Amazon edition is published by Cambridge. I am not sure that he actually gives a proof of the existence of such a set, but it is a good place to start, and he gives lots of references at the end of each chapter.

There is also another (older) book by Rogers on "Analytic Sets", but I don't have a copy so I can't check it.

Answer (score 5):

The projection of a Borel set in the square onto the $x$-axis is a so-called **analytic set** or **Souslin set** in the line.  So you are asking for an analytic set in the interval that is not a Borel set. That is, an analytic set whose complement is not analytic.   Any text on *descriptive set theory* should have such a construction.  For example:

Donald L. Cohn, *Measure Theory* (Birkhäuser, 1980)
Corollary 8.2.17, page 269

> There is an analytic subset of $\mathcal N$ that is not a Borel set.

Here, $\mathcal N$ is homeomorphic to the irrationals in $(0,1)$, for example.

As a consequence, any uncountable complete metric space has such a set as well.

Comment: I don't quite follow. If this Borel set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ exists, then its projection is analytic, but not Borel. So if you construct such an analytic set on the line, how does this give you the counterexample in $\mathbb{R}^2$?