# $B$ is a Borel set, implies $f(B)$ is a Borel set.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have this exercise:

> Suppose $f$ is a real valued continuous function on $[a,b]$. Show that
>   $f(B)$ is a Borel set for every Borel subset $B$ of $[a,b]$.
>
> Hint: Consider the collection $M$ of all subsets $A$ of $[a,b]$ for which
>   $f(A)$ is a Borel set. Show that $M$ is a sigma-algebra.

I am struggling a little. The hint tells me to look at:

$M=\{A\mid f(A) \text{ is Borel}\}$, and show that this is a sigma algebra. I do get that $\emptyset \in M$, and that M is closed under countable unions. But how do I get closed under complements?, I mean $A \in M \rightarrow A^c \in M$?, the problem is that we only have $f(A)^c=f(A^c)$
 if f is bijective.

And to finish the proof I also need that $f(O)$ is borel for every open set, but how do I get this?

Comment: The image of a Borel set under a continuous map is, in general, not Borel.

Comment: This is the mistake that Lebesgue, himself, did in his one of articles !

Comment: The hint is also wrong: since all closed subsets of $[a,b]$ have a Borel image, if $M$ were a $\sigma$-algebra, it would contain the $\sigma$-algebra generated by closed sets, which is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. That's probably the idea of the hint. But, while you can prove that a countable union of elements of $M$ is in $M$, it's not enough to show it's a $\sigma$-algebra. Since we know there is a Borel set not in $M$, then $M$ can't be a $\sigma$-algebra. Actually, while there is a nice equality $f(\bigcup_n A_n)=\bigcup_n f(A_n)$, there is no such thing for the complement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement you want to prove is wrong: There is a Borel set $B \subseteq [0,1]^2$ such that its projection $\pi_1[B]$ onto the first coordinate is not Borel (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603173/assumed-fact-about-borel-sets)). Now let $\gamma \colon [0,1] \to [0,1]^2$ a continuous onto map, and $f := \pi_1 \circ \gamma \colon [0,1]\to [0,1]$. Then, $f$ is continuous, $A := \gamma^{-1}[B]$ is Borel, but 
$$ f[A] = \pi_1[\gamma\gamma^{-1}[B]] = \pi_1[B] $$
is not.

Comment: Did you try further? I do not know at what step of the Borel hierarchy the statement breaks down, I'm sure that is also an interesting question.

Comment: So far, I have this: the continuous image of a compact is compact, and any closed subset of $[a,b]$ is compact, hence the image of a closed subset is a Borel set. Since $f(\bigcup_n A_n)=\bigcup_n f(A_n)$, taking $A_n$ to be closed, you get that the image of a $F_\sigma$ is also a Borel set.

Comment: Some further reading lead me to the result, that the $B$ above can be choosen to be a $G_\delta$, so nothing beyond $F_\sigma$ will work.