# Prove that there is exist Lebesgue measurable and non Borel measurable sets.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider a $\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$ - Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. It's easy to see that $\#\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}) = 2^{\aleph_0}$. And we now that $\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})\subset \mathfrak{L}(\mathbb{R})$ - Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra. 
I want to show that there is exist such subset of real line , which are Borel non measurable and Lebesgue measurable. But I don't know how?

Actually , I know about some examples. But maybe it possible to show easier than constructing a counterexample? For example I thought about finding some Lebesgue measurable sets , which are bigger than $\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$. And I thought about Cantor set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cantor set is a Lebesgue null set, so all of its subsets are Lebesgue measurable sets.  It has $2^{\mathfrak c}$ subsets.  But there are only $\mathfrak c$ Borel sets.  ( $\mathfrak c = 2^{\aleph_0}$)

Another method.  An [analytic set that is not Borel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603173/a-borel-set-whose-projection-onto-the-first-coordinate-is-not-a-borel-set)

Comment: Thanks , I thought about that!

Comment: Bad link.......

Comment: Link fixed again