# Measurability of the sup norm functional

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-measures

Let $(\mathbb{X}, \mathcal{X})$ and $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{R})$ denote a metric space and the real line, both endowed with their Borel $\sigma$-algebras. Let $\mathcal{X}\otimes\mathcal{R}$ denote the usual product $\sigma$-algebra and $f: \mathbb{X} \times\mathbb{R}\mapsto [-\infty, \infty]$ be a $\mathcal{X}\otimes\mathcal{R}$-measurable function.

**Q.1** Is it true that the map $x \mapsto \sup_{y \in \mathbb{R}}|f(x,y)|$ is $\mathcal{X}$-measurable?

The question might be silly, though I'm not managing to get a final answer. In particular, we know that, under the previous hypothesis, the map $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ is $\mathcal{X}$-measurable for every $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus, for any $\epsilon>0$, we have $B_{\epsilon,y}:=\{x \in \mathbb{X}: |f(x,y)|< \epsilon\} \in \mathcal{X}$. Though, we can not guarantee that the uncountable intersection  $B_\epsilon:=\cap_{y \in \mathbb{R}}B_{\epsilon,y}$ is still contained in $\mathcal{X}$. Whence I would conclude that the answer to **Q.1** is: no.  Is this correct?

If so:

**Q.2** are there additional conditions we can assume on $\mathbb{X}$ in order to have a positive answer? Can we obtain such a positive answer without requiring the continuity of the maps $y \mapsto f(x,y)$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{X}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: In general, no, not even when $\mathbb{X} = \mathbb{R}$.  [There exists a Borel subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ whose projection $\pi(A)$ onto the first coordinate is not a Borel set.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603173/a-borel-set-whose-projection-onto-the-first-coordinate-is-not-a-borel-set/603233#603233)  So taking $f$ to be the indicator function of $A$, the map $x \mapsto \sup_y |f(x,y)|$ is exactly the indicator of $\pi(A)$, and thus is not a Borel function.

Q2: Since $\mathbb{R}$ is about the nicest nontrivial space in measure theory, I don't think you will find any useful conditions on the space $\mathbb{X}$ to make this true.  I am not sure offhand as to conditions on $f$ that would help.

Comment: I was thinking to the following: let's replace $\mathbb{R}$ with $(0,1)$ and consider the sets $B_{\epsilon, n}=\cap_{i=1}^{n-1}\{x \in \mathbb{X}: |f(x, i/n)| < \epsilon\}$. Clearly, $B_{\epsilon, n} \in \mathcal{X}$. We also have $\cap_{n \geq 1} B_{\epsilon,n} \in \mathcal{X}$. Could this pave the way to prove that $x \mapsto \sup_{y \in (0,1)}|f(x,y)|$ is $\mathcal{X}$-measurable?

Comment: @JackLondon: That will only get you as far as showing that $x \mapsto \sup_{y \in (0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}} |f(x,y)|$ is measurable, which in general tells you very little about the sup over all of (0,1).  Unless of course $f$ is continuous in $y$.

Comment: @JackLondon: A positive result, however, is that if $\mathbb{X}$ is Polish, then your function will be [universally measurable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_measurable_set); i.e. for every $\sigma$-finite Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{X}$, your function is $\mu$-a.e. equal to a Borel function (where the null set may of course depend on $\mu$).  This is because the sets $\{x : \sup_y |f(x,y)| > a\}$, while not necessarily Borel, are analytic.