# Are Borel sets whose projections are Borel closed under intersection?

Tags: measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

The projection of a Borel set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ [needn't be Borel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603173/a-borel-set-whose-projection-onto-the-first-coordinate-is-not-a-borel-set), although the projection of a closed set is a countable union of compact sets, hence Borel.

My question is if $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ are Borel such that $\pi_k(A), \pi_k(B)$ are known to be Borel, is it true $\pi_k(A \cap B)$ is Borel?

I haven't found an easy way to prove this, and can't find an answer, but it feels possible because intersecting seems limited in how much it can sabotage the projections. I proved a geometric theorem about such sets/projections, but lack that the projections are Borel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Negative example.

Let $T \subseteq [0,1]\times[0,1]$ be a Borel set with non-Borel projection $\pi_1(T)$ on the first coordinate.  Let $S = [0,1]\times[0,1]$ be the quare.  Our sets are made up of vertical translates of these two:
$$
A = T \cup (S + (0,2)),
\\
B = T  \cup (S + (0,5)),
$$
so that $\pi_1(A) = [0,1]$ is Borel,
$\pi_1(B) = [0,1]$ is Borel, but
$\pi_1(A\cap B) = \pi_1(T)$ is not Borel.